# Dual Homed to speed communication between two servers

Tags: multi-homed, nic

I have to RHEL 6.4 servers that each have 1000 Mbps Full Duplex NIC Cards.  However, the switch between them is only 100 Mbps.

Is there any downside to setting both servers up as dual-homed and use a crossover cable between the two to get faster throughput between them?  All other routing would go through the existing connection.

Comment: You won't be able to port mirror on the switch to sniff traffic... I can't think of any major draw backs but it has been awhile since i did any server->server networking without a switch..

Answer (score 2):

Direct connection between two servers is no problem.

In some systems this is even designed to be like that. Some solution use such a link to run replication, keep alive checks over such a device as the chance of a failure is very low because no components are involved that could die. Of course you can only connect 2 servers that way and you can not mirror the port as you can with a network switch. But if you do not need that, that is perfectly OK.